# What's the best CMS for my project?

Tags: cms

I'm new to content management systems and I have very little experience in web development.
Which CMS do you recommend for the following tasks?

- Users can login and create list items
- Users can upload files to list items
- Users can comment and rate uploads (thumbs up down)
- Users are able to change the font size of the page via mouse click
- Users are able to export sites to pdf via mouse click
- Breadcrumbs
- Small and easy to use forum
- Users can change the language of the site

So far I experimented with Wordpress, but I think it's not the optimal choice!

I've to use MySql as database.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using plug-ins and widgets with wordpress?
You can try using Drupal. 
Wordpress today is not just a blogging website. You can use wordpress to create stynning websites with lots of features provided you have a descent knowledge of PHP and Mysql.

You can search on the Internet for plug-ins that meet your requirements.

Since you have already started with wordpress, I would recommend you to continue with it.

You can check out: http://en.support.wordpress.com/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend using Wordpress. Like Nilabh said, Wordpress isn't just a blogging software anymore. I used it as a CMS for my lastest project and I am happy with my choice. I would recommend that you check out the [Wordpress plugins directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/). I like Wordpress better for user management, but most of the things on your list can be achieved out-of-the-box with [Joomla!](http://joomla.org) Joomla also has many plugins, but many of them aren't free. Especially if you want to bridge Joomla with a forum software, you will have to pay some money.